# service Method = "DELETE". Method not allowed

Tags: rest, wcf

The contract of my method is like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           UriTemplate = "/myMethod/{param}/", 
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
void myMethod(string param);
```

I test it via Fiddler.

```
http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc/jsonMS/myMethod/1/
```

I get the error 'Method not allowed.'.

Comment: @marc_s I configure it via web.config, it's an endpoint.

Comment: @marc_s That was it, I didn't test in Fiddler in the right way. I used GET. Can you answer pls, so that I can choose your answer as the best?

Comment: marc_s, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you test this method in Fiddler, you need to make sure to:

- send a JSON request to your URL
- use the HTTP `DELETE` method (not `GET`) when calling this method